# _vue2.default.locale is not a function

Tags: vue.js

When I used vue-i18n in my project, the program threw me this error:_vue2.default.locale is not a function，

vue vision: 1.0,
vue-i18n vision: 6.1.0

**My code:**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueForm from 'vue-form'
import router from './config/routes'
import App from './App'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

var locales = {
  en: {
    message: {
      hello: 'hello world'
    }
  },
  ja: {
    message: {
      hello: 'こんにちは、世界'
    }
  }
}

Vue.use(VueI18n)

Vue.config.lang = 'ja'

Object.keys(locales).forEach(function (lang) {
  Vue.locale(lang, locales[lang])
})

router.start(App, '#app')
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="row border-bottom white-bg">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h2 class="page-title">{{ $t("message.hello") }}</h2>
      <!--<h2 class="page-title">基本信息</h2>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

error:

Uncaught TypeError: _vue2.default.locale is not a function

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add your code into the question instead of using a link to it?

Comment: OK，above is my code, trouble you help, very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vue-i18n in 6.1.0 version is compatible only with vue2.0.0+
Edit: 
According to Your post, you used 1.0 version of vue.
So... update Vue to 2.0.0 version or if you have to use 1.0 downgrade vue-i18n to v4.10.0

Comment: It can work, very very grateful! It is really wrong version～